# Intersection of dependent events with probability half contains a large enough intersection

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

We are given $n \geq 4$ and $A_1,...,A_n$ probability events (which may be dependent), such that $P(A_i) = \frac{1}{2}$ for every $i$. Prove or disprove: There exist a subset of $n/4$ events such that the probability of all of them happening simultaneously is at least $\frac{1}{4}$. In other words, there exist events $A_{i_1},...,A_{i_{n/4}}$ such that:

$ P(A_{i_1}\cap ... \cap A_{i_{n/4}}) \geq \frac{1}{4}$

My intuition is that it is true. It can be thought of as trying to fit $n$ subsets of measure $\frac{1}{2}$ into the interval $[0,1]$ without any $n/4$ of them intersecting by a subset of measure larger than $\frac{1}{4}$ which looks impossible.

Comment: What if all the events are independent?

Comment: Then I think it is still true. Consider for example n random coin tosses. The probability that any n/4 of them are heads is clearly larger than 1/4.

Comment: Yes, but the way you write it, you want to select the coins before they are thrown (roughly speaking).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant to ask whether there exist any n/4 events which happen at the same time w.p > 1/4. We can choose the events "after they happen" in some sense. I think that the difficult case is where there is some dependence which is unknown.

Comment: Maybe it is more useful to think about the continuous case rather than the discrete one, as it is less obvious there. You can think about the problem as if each A_i is a subset of [0,1] with measure 1/2. Then, if we draw x uniformly from [0,1], the probability that x \in A_i is 1/2. The question is then, whether there exist any n/4 subsets A_i such that their intersection has a measure of at least 1/4.

Comment: If you want to show $P[\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{A_i}\geq n/4]\geq 1/3$, where $X=\sum_{i=1}^n1_{A_i}$ counts the number of events that occur, you can do it with the Markov inequality on $Y=n-X$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer indeed this seems like a better formulation, although I'm not sure I understand it completely. What I was looking for is that the *same* n/4 events happen with probability >1/4 (or 1/3 which is even better). Using Markov and your answer, we know that the probability that n/4 events happen at the same time is large, but we don't know if these are the same events.  Saying it slightly differently, I want to show $P(\exists A_{i_1},...,A_{i_{n/4}}, \sum_{j=1}^{n/4} 1_{A_{i_j}} \geq n/4) \geq 1/4$

Comment: No, you are not making any sense.  $P[\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{A_i}\geq n/4]$ is the probability that at least $n/4$ of the identified $n$ events occur. If you want to fix which events in advance, then PhoemueX and Mike Earnest have already answered your question. It does not make sense to talk about the "same" events (what does that even mean?) Also, your "new" expression $P[\exists A_{i_1}, ..., A_{i_{n/4}}, \sum_{j=1}^{n/4} 1_{A_{i_j}}\geq n/4]$, if we assume you want the $A_{i_j}$ to be distinct, seems to be a more complicated way of writing $P[\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{A_i}\geq n/4]$.

Comment: Let me give a specific instance of the problem, hopefully, it will be clearer. Suppose we are given $U_1,...,U_n \subseteq[0,1]$ where $\mu(U_i) = 1/2$ for every $i$. Consider the event $A_i$ to be $x\in U_i$ where $x$ is drawn uniformly from $[0,1]$, then $P(A_i) = P(x\in U_i) = 1/2$. My question is, does there exist events $A_{i_1},...,A_{i_{n/4}}$ such that $P(A_{i_1}\cap ...\cap A_{i_{n/4}}) = P(x \in U_{i_1}\cap ...\cap U_{i_{n/4}}) \geq 1/4$? 
I'm not sure if your response using Markov answers this question, but I may be missing something.

Comment: What is the context in which problem arises? That is, why is it important to you to be able to prove the existence of these $n//4$ events? I ask, because we have tried asking you to clarify the mathematical formulation, but you seem to be unable to do that, so asking context is the only way to figure out what you really want/need.

Comment: The exact formulation of the question I am looking for is in my previous comment about the unit interval. I understand that the way I wrote the question, there is a very simple counter-example with independent events, so I should have asked it more specifically about this instance. There is some context behind it, but I think it is irrelevant once the question is formulated correctly as above. Anyway, I'm ok with leaving this question as is, since it is wrongly formulated, and you indeed gave the simple counter-example, and perhaps later I'll ask another one with the right formulation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false whenever $n\ge 12$. Phoemuex’s comment is correct; you get a counterexample when the events are independent. This is because
$$
P(A_{i_1}\cap\dots\cap A_{i_{n/4}})=(1/2)^{n/4}\le (1/2)^3=1/8
$$

To be concrete, choose a random number uniformly at random between $0$ and $2^n-1$. For each $i$, let $A_i$ be the event that the $i^\text{th}$ binary digit of the chosen number is equal to $1$.

Comment: You have correctly answered the question that was asked, but from comments it looks like the OP really wants to show $P[\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{A_i}\geq n/4]\geq 1/4$. In fact the probability has a bound that is larger than 1/4.

Comment: @Michael I do not think that OP knows what OP wants.